# PHP won't interpret heredoc string

Tags: php, string, heredoc

I am using PHP '5.6.16' and it refuses to interpret that Heredoc string with exception:  Parse error: syntax error, unexpected end of file in ..... on line 131

131 is the end of the file. Without the heredoc string all interprets well.

```
$data = <<<DATA
MIN={$min}
INVOICE={$invoice}
AMOUNT={$sum}
EXP_TIME={$exp_date}
DESCR={$descr}
DATA;
```

I have tried with a simple heredoc string with no success.

```
$data = <<<EOD
foobar!
EOD;
```

Any idea what it might be?

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/q/3446216/3933332

Comment: Are you sure that there is no white-space character before ending identifier?

Comment: If I remove the heredoc string everything works fine.